# displaying the angular get response in html table format in a div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-fullstack

I am working on angular-fullstack generator. I am getting the data in response of get request which is in form of integer values
 (1 ,2 
 5,6 
 134, 245 
 236,567 
 415,234 and so on)
I want to show these values in my front end in form of html table with two columns that it will look like following

```
     col1  col2
       1    2
       5    6
      134   245 and so on
```

below is my html div where i want to display it

```
 <div id="tabdata" >

 </div>
```

My angular controller code for http get

```
$scope.getdata =function(){
$http.get("/getdata" ).success(function(response){
$scope.output=response;
})
```

The table should be get adjusted according to the content coming from the response.
Thanks in advance for reply.

Comment: Have you tried anything to generate your table?

Comment: Does it's response like this 1,2,5,6 or  like

1,2  --first row
5,6 --2nd row

Answer (score 1):

Read about [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Based on structure of your data, you could use something like

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in dataset">
    <td ng-repeat="cell in row">{{cell.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

You could of course write your own directive, or if you know the incoming structure beforehand,specify cells accordingly (as to avoid nested repeat)

[Tracking](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates) can be useful for larger datasets